# receiving nth character when trying to access JSON values

Tags: json

Having trouble with accessing json values formed from php array

```
var latlag = '<?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>';
```

`alert(latlng)` produces:

```
[{
  "1280":{"lat":"-1.197070","lng":"-1.197070"},
  "1239":{"lat":"-1.222410","lng":"-1.222410"},
  "1258":{"lat":"-1.153020","lng":"-1.153020"},
...
}]
```

I've tried all sorts of ways to access lat and lag for a specific ID and the only result other than undefined has been the nth character of `latlng` as if its being treated like a string?!

```
alert(latlng[10]); # {
alert(latlng[1280]['lat]); # undefined 
alert(latlng['1280'].lat); # undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to put the JSON in quotes, so:

```
var latlag = <?php echo json_encode($coordinates); ?>;
```

*(Technically, that's not JSON at all, it's a JavaScript object initializer. But that's fine, JSON is a subset of initializer syntax and so all valid JSON texts are also valid JavaScript initializers.)*

If the structure is really as you've quoted it, it's an array with **one** entry, which is an object with properties with names like `1280` and `1258`, whose values are objects with properties named `lat` and `lng`. So you'd access those like this:

```
alert(latlng[0]["1280"].lat);
```

`latlng` is the array, `latlng[0]` is the one object it holds, and `latlng[0]["1280"]` is the `{"lat":"-1.197070","lng":"-1.197070"}` object.

You may be wondering why I've used quotes around `1280` above. It's because those keys are clearly given as strings (as is required in JSON, though not in JavaScript initializers), and so I can't be sure there aren't entries like `"0012"`. Property names are *always* strings even when not written as strings, so `latlng[0][1280]` and `latlng["0"]["1280"]` both mean the same thing (because the `0` and the `1280` are converted to string [yes, really]), but naturally `latlng[0]["0012"]` is not the same as `latlng[0][12]` because the latter uses `"12"`, not `"0012"`, as the property name. If you *know* you won't have leading zeros, you can ditch the quotes.

Comment: thankyou! the first [] were put in as mistake(as you probably thought!) so have used `latlng["1280"].lat` and works like a dream :)

Comment: @JPickup: Ah, glad that helped! I wasn't sure about the `[]` -- I've used APIs with lots weirder return structures... ;-)